# Проверка на наличие сразу двух классов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо, чтобы с помощью jQuery появлялся блок имеющий два определенных класса.
Например, если я делаю фильтр в интернет магазине и мне нужно чтобы после выбора **одновременно цвета и размера** товара, на экран выводились товары такого размера, среди всех товаров такого цвета. Пока что он выводит только все товары с таким цветом и все товары с таким размером(они не только необходимого цвета). Как исправить?
Я задаю всем товарам магазина классы с их цветом и размером.

```js
function FILT(){
 var color;
  var first_check = false;
  $(".monitors").hide();

  if ($('#c_black').is(':checked')){ 
   $(".black").show();
   first_check=true;
   $(".black").addClass('chosen');
  }
  if ($('#c_grey').is(':checked')){ 
   $(".grey").show();
   first_check=true;
   $(".grey").addClass('chosen');
  }
  if ($('#c_white').is(':checked')){ 
   $(".white").show();
   first_check=true;
   $(".white").addClass('chosen');
  }


  if (first_check===true) {



   if ($('#sml').is(':checked')){ 
    $(".sml.chosen").show();
   }
   if ($('#mid').is(':checked')){ 
    $(".lar.chosen").show();
   }
   if ($('#lar').is(':checked')){ 
    $(".lar.chosen").show();
   }




  }
  else{

   if ($('#sml').is(':checked')){ 
    $(".sml").show();
   }
   if ($('#mid').is(':checked')){ 
    $(".lar").show();
   }
   if ($('#lar').is(':checked')){ 
    $(".lar").show();
   }
  }
var count = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
  if (count==0) {
   $(".monitors").show();
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Айди размеров (lag,mid...)- это от чекбоксов, а классы размеров от товаров*

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".color-class.size-class").show();
```